# Border-radius on image not working on mobiles - safari

Tags: css, safari, gatsby, gatsby-image, border-radius

I have seen that similar posts already exist... the solutions posted there did not work for me tho. Sorry for asking again.

In my gatsby project I want a solid border and border-radius on an image. On Chrome it looks as expected but on mobile devices and Safari the image just does not get the rounded corners and overflows the border. How can I fix this?

```css
.imgContainer {
  border: solid 1px #0784b5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div className={styles.imgContainer}>
  <GatsbyImage className={styles.img} 
  image={data.file.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} 
  alt="portrait" 
  />
</div>
```

[image: Expected output]

[image: How it looks on Safari]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: sometimes -webkit-border-radius is needed for safari

.imgContainer {
  border: solid 1px #0784b5;
  border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

just added to your class

Comment: Gatsby Images both static and non, are absolutely position, you need to add overflow hidden to the wrapper. Look at the DOM tree for .gatsby-image-wrapper (which is a div), the elements within are positioned absolutely too them, so an overflow is caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gatsby-image package is now deprecated

You can use: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/

Ex:

```
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

const IndexPage = () => (
  <StaticImage
    src="../images/test_image.jpg"
    alt=""
    imgStyle={{ borderRadius: '20%' }}
  />
);
```

Comment: This seems to work! I will test it deeper tomorrow. Thanks!
Do you know if in another page I upload images through a CMS... is it ok to use static image or would it be better gatsby image? Just wondering :)